# Exact string match in vim? (Like 'regex-off' mode in less.)

Tags: search, vim, escaping

In *vim*, I often want to search on a string with finicky characters which need escaping. Is there a way I can turn off the meaning of all special characters, kind of like *regex-off* mode in less, or *fgrep*?

I am dealing with particularly hairy strings; here's an example:

```
((N/N)/(N/N))/N
```

Not having to escape any characters to do a search in vim would be a major timesaver.

\V in *Vim* helps with some metacharacters, but critically not / or \.

---

Thanks all! In the end, I added this to my .vimrc:

```
command! -nargs=1 S let @/ = escape('<args>', '\')
nmap <Leader>S :execute(":S " . input('Regex-off: /'))<CR>
```

Comment: In `less`, you can turn off regex with `/` `Ctrl-R`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looking at your specific example, probably the easiest way to do this (since \V won't help here) is to use `?` instead of `/`: then you won't have to escape the `/`s:

```
?((N/N)/(N/N))/N
```

This will search backwards instead of forwards, but you can always do 'N' instead of 'n' to search forwards after the first go.  Or you can press `/` followed by the up cursor key to automatically escape the forward slashes.

However, there's nothing you can easily do about escaping backslashes.  I guess you could do:

```
:let @/ = escape(pattern, '\')
```

and then use `n` to search, but it's probably not much easier.  The best I can come up with is:

```
:command! -nargs=1 S let @/ = escape('<args>', '\')
```

Then do:

```
:S (N)/(N+1)\(N)
n
```

Comment: Great answers, but escaping the input is probably the closest I'll get to No-regex. No search as you type, but then again neither does 'less'!

Comment: :g#((N/N)/(N/N))/N##! works for your example.  For search-as-you-type, ?((N/N)/(N/N))/N also works, but searches backwards.

Answer (score 36):

Depending on the exact string you're searching, the `\V` prefix will probably do the trick.
See [`:help \V`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic):

```
after:    \v       \m       \M       \V         matches ~
                'magic' 'nomagic'    
          $        $        $        \$         matches end-of-line
          .        .        \.       \.         matches any character
          *        *        \*       \*         any number of the previous atom
          ()       \(\)     \(\)     \(\)       grouping into an atom
          |        \|       \|       \|         separating alternatives
          \a       \a       \a       \a         alphabetic character
          \\       \\       \\       \\         literal backslash
          \.       \.       .        .          literal dot
          \{       {        {        {          literal '{'
          a        a        a        a          literal 'a'
```

So if I have a string `hello.*$world`, I can use the command `/\V.*$` to find just `.*$` -- the only part of the *string* that should need escaping is another backslash, but you can still do grouping, etc., by escaping the special symbol.

---

Another command you can use to "avoid" forward slashes is:

```
:g #\V((N/N)/(N/N))/N#
```

The [`:g`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/repeat.html#multi-repeat) command is a global search, noting that:

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
                        Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
                        lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.

Instead of the '/' which surrounds the {pattern}, you can use any other
single byte character, but not an alphanumeric character, '\', '"' or '|'.
This is useful if you want to include a '/' in the search pattern or
replacement string.
```

So where I used a `#`, you could  use a `?`, `@`, or whatever other character meeting the above condition.  The catch with that `:g` command is that it expects a command at the end, so if you do not have a trailing space after the final character, it won't perform the search as you would expect.  And again, even though you're using `\V`, you'll still have to escape backslashes.

If that *still* doesn't cut it for you, [this Nabble post](http://www.nabble.com/Re%3A-search-and-replace-with-many-special-characters-p23102604.html) has a suggestion that takes a literal string with embedded backslashes and other special Vim characters, and claims to search for it without a problem; but it requires creating a Vim function, which may or may not be okay in your environment.

Comment: Thanks Mark! But I'm trying to match strings which are probably purpose-built to frustrate vim's escaping. I've edited the question with an example.

Are you aware of any way to get rid of the meaning of _all_ special metacharacters, including \ and /, just like /usr/bin/less with no-regex (Ctrl+R) does?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this:

```
nmap <Leader>s :execute '/\V' . escape(input('/'), '\\/')<CR>
```

It'll give you a `/` prompt and behave otherwise like the built-in search, but it won't do search-as-you-type or other such goodies.

Comment: (This uses `:/`, which works line-based, so it puts the cursor at the beginning of the match's line;  (as opposed to `/`, which jumps to the match's position within its line.))

Comment: The second ``\`` in `escape(…, '\\/')` is redundant, because `escape()`'s second parameter is a list of characters, and single quotes denote a [`'…'` literal string](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#literal-string) where no escape sequences are interpreted.  (I suggest writing `'/\'` to make it visually apparent that the ``\`` does not escape the `/`.)